# Difference between "get" and "navigate" method in Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
get("https://www.google.com/");
```

waiting once everything is loaded

```
navigate("https://www.google.com/");
```

immediately starts looking for the next step

also has methods:

- navigate().forward();
- navigate().back();
- navigate().refresh();

What else?

Answer (score 0):

`navigate("https://www.google.com/");` is not a valid use of the method. I think you meant,

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
```

According to [the docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java) for `get()`, the two are synonyms (the same)

> Synonym for {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation#to(String)}.

As for the other methods, `.forward()` and `.back()` uses the browser navigation history to move forwards and back. `.refresh()` refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

### get()

[`get()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get-java.lang.String-) is a method in the [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface which extends the [SearchContext](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L49) and is defined as:

```
/**
 * Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using an HTTP POST operation,
 * and the method will block until the load is complete.
 * This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as a meta-redirect from within the
 * returned HTML.
 * Synonym for {@link org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Navigation#to(String)}.
 */
void get(String url);
```

- Usage:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```

---

### navigate()

[`navigate()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#navigate--) is an [abstraction](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L463) allowing the driver to access the browser's history and to navigate to a given URL. The methods and their usage are as follows:

- `to(java.lang.String url)`: Load a new web page in the current browser window.

  ```
  driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
  ```
- `to(java.net.URL url)`: Overloaded version of to(String) that makes it easy to pass in a URL.
- `refresh()`: Refresh the current page.

  ```
  driver.navigate().refresh();
  ```
- `back()`: Move back a single "item" in the browser's history.

  ```
  driver.navigate().back();
  ```
- `forward()`: Move a single "item" forward in the browser's history.

  ```
  driver.navigate().forward();
  ```